# setSize of JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

Trying to set size of a JOptionPane but it's sticking with the same size. I've tried setPreferredSize and setSize but for some reason the JOptionPane is sticking with the same width and height. 
Basically I have a bunch of text and it's being "cut off" because of the size of the window.

I'm actually using a port of the swing library in another language, so it could be a bug with their library - but according to the docs it should mirror the Java Swing calls.

Am I missing something?

- edit - wanted to add that I create the joptionpane with JOptionPane.showInputDialog
- edit again - i'm using ASwing (actionscript port of Java Swing - hence there might be api differences though it's supposed to be a
  port...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, found the fix. The ported library built the JOptionPane I guess slightly different than the Java version.

```
optionpane.getFrame().setSize()
```

(using ASwing - Actionscript port of Java Swing)

Answer (score 5):

It is good idea to create a JPanel with prefereed size or JTextArea with JScrollPane scrollbars and add it to optionpan.

**It's easy to do, and not only sets the size of the dialog but allows great flexibility of content.**

```
JTextArea mytext = new JTextArea();
mytext.setText("mytextline1\nmytextline2\nmytextline3\nmytextline4\nmytextline5\nmytextline6");
mytext.setRows(5);
mytext.setColumns(10);
mytext.setEditable(true);
JScrollPane mypane = new JScrollPane(mytext);

Object[] objarr = {
    new JLabel("Enter some text:"),
    mypane,
};

JOptionPane Optpane = new JOptionPane(objarr, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

see [details](http://inversionconsulting.blogspot.com/2009/06/java-joptionpane-examples-part-4.html)

Answer (score 3):

Check the layout manager of the container

Answer (score 0):

You can just as well override setSize by extending our Componemt:

```
public class Headerfield extends JLabel
{
    public Headerfield(String text)
    {
        super(text);
    }

    public void setSize(int width, int height)
    {
        super.setSize(100, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: many roads to Rome - violating method contracts is not one of them ;-)